# Inner rounded bottom radius using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create a shape with bottom rounded corner like this -

[image: Shape I want to Create]

How could i achieve this task using CSS?

Comment: You might want to try SVG. Create the shape in SVG editor (Sketch or Illustrator). Open SVG file in file editor and paste code in your code. It won't be a container though for the "search now" text. Or simply use the SVG as a background-image in a container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### SVG Based Approaches:

CSS might not be the best way to create such shapes. You should use SVG instead.

**1- Using `path` Element:**

We can use SVG's `path` element to create this shape and fill it with some color, gradient or pattern.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shapes in `path` element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

Below is the necessary code to create this shape:

```
<path d="M0,0 0,20
         Q25,25 50,50
         Q75,25 100,25
         L100,0 Z" />
```

I've used 4 commands inside `path` element. Below is a brief description:

- `M` command is used to define the starting point. It appears at the beginning and specify the point from where drawing should start.
- `Q` command is used to draw curves.
- `L` command is used to draw straight lines.
- `Z` command is used to close the current path.

*Working Example:*

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0,0 0,20
           Q25,25 50,50
           Q75,25 100,25
           L100,0 Z" fill="brown" />
</svg>
```

---

**2- Clipping:**

Clipping means removing or hiding some parts of an element.

In this approach, we define a clipping region by using SVG's `clipPath` element and apply this to a rectangular element. Any area that is outside the clipping region will be hidden.

Below is the necessary code:

```
<defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0,0 0,20
               Q25,25 50,50
               Q75,25 100,25
               L100,0 Z" />
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="brown" clip-path="url(#shape)"/>
```

- `defs` element is used to define element / objects for later use in SVG document.
- `clipPath` element is used to define a clipping region.
- `rect` element is used to create rectangles.
- `clip-path` attribute is used to link the clipping path created earlier.

*Working Example:*

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 50"
     preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0,0 0,20
               Q25,25 50,50
               Q75,25 100,25
               L100,0 Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="brown" clip-path="url(#shape)"/>
</svg>
```

---

### CSS Based Approach:

**1- Using Rotated Pseudo Elements with Large Box-Shadow Values:**

1. Create 2 `<div>` elements inside a parent element.
2. Use `::before` or `::after` pseudo element to draw overlays of small `height` and `border-radius`.
3. Apply a few degree rotation with CSS3 `rotate()` transformation.
4. Apply large `box-shadow` values and adjust them to look like the final shape.

*Output Image:*

[image: Output Image]

*Working Example:*

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80px;
}

.left,
.right {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}

.left:before,
.right:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 150px brown;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  height: 100px;
  content: '';
  width: 200%;
  left: -10%;
}

.left:before {
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
   right: -10%;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Useful Resources:**

- CSS3 Transforms: [Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-property), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- SVG: [Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)

Comment: It's working good in chrome at all window width. But when run on safari it's create some problem at some window width. Please have a look on jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/urrwen60/

Comment: @IshanJain Does the white separator is problem that is appearing on some widths?

Comment: Yes, white seperator.

Comment: @IshanJain [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/urrwen60/2/) is a better Fix. You can use a pseudo element of parent to create a thin (`1px` or `2px`) stip of same color like shadow and place it exactly in center.

Comment: Thanks you so much.